# Code works in .Net 5 but doesn't work in .Net 6

Tags: c#, .net-5, stringbuilder, .net-6.0

I have reported this possible bug via the Visual Studio feedback tool but I have the following example code that runs in .Net 5 but doesn't work correctly in .Net 6 and I feel like this is either a bug or I'm missing something that changed between versions. I have the example code below along with the html output using the Visual Studio html visualizer from both methods. Does anyone have any possible input on this issue?

UPDATE: From different testing thanks to helpful suggestions from @GSerg I have found that this bug only happens in .Net 6 when you use html tags inside of a string interpolation or a stringbuilder and it chops off the text before the inserted variable and inserts it on the second line. I have attached a new screenshot showing this behavior using the visual studio visualizer.

```cs
var subect = "Subect Example";
var test = $"<p><strong><span style=\"font-size: 20px;\">{subject}</span></strong></p><p><span style=\"color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; " +
           $"font-size: small; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; " +
           $"text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration-thickness: initial; " +
           $"text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial; display: inline !important; float: none;\">The following information is in beta testing and isn't meant for a live portfolio. " +
           $"Use this information for paper trading only until further notice.</span></p>";
```

.Net 5 HTML Output:
[image]

.Net 6 HTML Output:
[image]

.Net 6 Text Output:
[image]

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with `StringBuilder`. It seems whatever control you're using to display the string has changed. Likely, it escapes the input to prevent injection attacks.

Comment: How are you displaying the content of the StringBuilder (the HTML side) ? also why are you using `+` instead of using `StringBuilder.append`

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft This is the Visual Studio [string vizualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/view-strings-visualizer?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @Darth So you are arguing that in .NET 6 the contents of the first *source code line* is lost in your concatenation expression (for which you don't need a stringbuiler in the first place)? Does it also happen if you remove the StringBuilder as you are not using it meaningfully anyway, and only leave the concatenation? Does it happen if you remove the string interpolation? Does it happen if you restart your computer?

Comment: From the docs: *'View HTML string data
A well-formed HTML string appears as if rendered in a browser, as shown in the following illustration. Malformed HTML may display as plain text.'* Your `test` variable doesn't contain valid html, (<html> tag is missing) so it behaves as expected.

Comment: @GSerg probably you should edit the question to make that clarification. As currently stands question missing [MCVE] (or if you are right missing explanation what OP is actually doing as it sounds like a difference in IDE behavior).

Comment: @Steeeve I'm using the same exact string for both tests and I attached the screenshots for the html visualizer for both. Literally the only difference between the two tests was the version of .net I was using

Comment: @GSerg Yes correct. First off it still happens even if I remove the string builder. I'm using the string builder correctly but didn't paste my full code because I just wanted to paste a minimul reproducible example for everyone here. It still happens when I remove the string builder and only leave the concatenation. It still happens when I restart my computer. It works however when I remove the string interpolation. My best guess is that string interpolation has a bug in the latest .Net because the problem only happens when using html code in a string. Run my code and see for yourself

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov This is the definition of a minimal reproducible example. All you need is Visual Studio and just paste this code into a basic console app project

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez Using visual studio html visualizer and visual studio does the + automatically when you insert line breaks

Comment: Many tools do many things automatically, is up to us to decide if is good enough for our standards

Comment: @Steeeve mentioned that tag is not closed correctly, did you check on that ? also when frameworks change versions, behavior change 100% code compatibility is never the case.

Comment: @DarthVegan You probably want to edit your question to reflect your findings (remove the mention of string builder, explain that it's the string interpolation, and mention the VS vizualizer explicitly). What is the actual string content, as seen in a "dumb" view (Locals window or Debug.Print)? Does it actually have the first line?

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez he was incorrect about needing the html tags. Try it for yourself and you can see that adding the html tags does nothing

Comment: @GSerg I did edit my question to reflect my findings but as you can see from the text view I added, it is chopping off the text from before the variable and swapping it with the text that is after the variable

Comment: How are you assigning the string to the html? Post that. Also how are you seeing the Text Visualizer?

Comment: The VS expression evaluator is rather notorious for having different behavior in executing managed code standalone (and/or misrepresenting results). If you can reproduce this in a *standalone* program (so no VS, and with the contents of `subject`), that would be interesting. My attempts at a standalone reproduction (using sharplab.io) certainly fail. There certainly have been many implementation changes in .NET 6 with regards to string interpolation, so a bug is not completely out of the question, but this one seems fundamental enough that it would have probably stuck out earlier.

Comment: @mxmissile I'm not assigning the string to the html. I'm using html inside of a string for creating a html message that I send via email. I updated my question to show what I see in the text visualizer and I'm inserting a breakpoint right after the test variable and looking at the text visualizer for the test variable in vs 2022

Comment: @JeroenMostert I do know that it is rather notorious but I'm not sure if you saw my updated question but I have the reproducible code and the screenshot of the text visualizer showing how it is cutting the text out and swapping it with other text so it definitely looks like a bug. I'm able to reproduce this in different versions of visual studio so far. How exactly did you try to reproduce this on your end?

Comment: Like I said, I just plugged the string interpolation code snippet into sharplab.io (which conveniently typically has the latest branch), to see if the runtime/JIT itself might be miscompiling this. If you can reproduce it *outside of Visual Studio* (that is, a `Console.WriteLine` shows an incorrect value) then it is much more likely there's a problem worth investigating (and then you should post a *complete, runnable program*); if it only fails inside Visual Studio, then it's a neat bug for the VS developers to dig into, but there's hardly any point for other people to do so.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes I am able to reproduce this error using Console.WriteLine as well and I can show my console output if you want

Comment: The program would be more interesting -- that is, something `dotnet run` can build and run while demonstrating the incorrect value. Then you have a bug that is completely independent from Visual Studio, and then it's much more likely you have something that can end up as a [bug report for .NET itself](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Visual Studio 2022 which is still in preview so it's not unexpected.
While this bug is not fixed you can use the dotnet cli to build as a workaround.

The following code reproduces the bug

```cs
string two= "2";
string test = $"1 {two} 3" 
    + $" 4" 
    + $" 5";
Console.WriteLine(test);
```

When building this code as .NET 6.0 with Visual Studio 2022 preview 3.1 the code is compiled to

```cs
    string two = "2";
    DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler defaultInterpolatedStringHandler = new DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler(8, 1);
    defaultInterpolatedStringHandler.AppendLiteral(" 3");
    defaultInterpolatedStringHandler.AppendFormatted(two);
    defaultInterpolatedStringHandler.AppendLiteral("1 ");
    defaultInterpolatedStringHandler.AppendLiteral(" 4");
    defaultInterpolatedStringHandler.AppendLiteral(" 5");
    string test = defaultInterpolatedStringHandler.ToStringAndClear();
    Console.WriteLine(test);
```

which produces the output  `321  4 5`

But this is specific to building .NET 6.0 with Visual Studio. When building with `dotnet build`
The code is compiled to

```cs
    string two = "2";
    string test = "1 " + two + " 3 4 5";
    Console.WriteLine(test);
```

Which produces the correct output.